# Passing a string object as a second parameter in an onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundcloud

I know there's something wrong with how I placed my quotes on track.title but for the love of god I can't figure it out. Please help!! The problem is with passing track.title. Everything else (track.id, track.artwork_url) works just fine. Maybe its a string concatenation issue?? What I want to do is pass the track.ID, so I can play the track, and the track.title so I can show the name of the track being played. Therefore, the parameters are playerPlayNewClick(trackid, trackname)

```
$("#result_container").append(
            "<div id='result-"+index+"'>"+
              " <a href='#' class='play' id='"+index+
              "' onClick='playerPlayNewClick("+track.id + "," \''+track.title + '\' +  ")'>" +
              "<img class = 'albumartwork' id='artwork-" + index + "' src=" + track.artwork_url + "></a> ");
```

Comment: Build your elements with the DOM, instead of strings; it's much less error prone.

Comment: does track.title have any quotes in it?

Comment: @elclanrs—but that's not "the jQuery way"!!

Comment: This part `"," \'` looks very wrong. What do you expect `","` followed by `\'` to do? `'\' +  ")'>"` is also very strange.

Comment: @NG—probably not in it, but likely it needs quotes *around* it. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be on this line; you can tell by the syntax highlighting that something is not right with `track.title`:

```
"' onClick='playerPlayNewClick("+track.id + "," \''+track.title + '\' +  ")'>" +
```

But, I'd suggest you build your elements with the DOM, instead of strings; it's much less error prone, and jQuery makes it easy:

```
var $div = $('<div>', {
  id: 'result-'+ index
});

var $a = $('<a>', {
  href: '#',
  class: 'play',
  id: index,
  click: function() {
    playerPlayNewClick(track.id, track.title)
  }
});

var $img = $('<img>', {
  class: 'albumartwork',
  id: 'artwork-'+ index,
  src: track.artwork_url
});

$('#result_container').append(
  $div.append(
    $a.append(
      $img
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to quotes. I understand you have a track variable and want to pass the value of track.title same as you do with track.id.

```
$("#result_container").append(
        "<div id='result-"+index+"'>"+
          " <a href='#' class='play' id='"+index+
          "' onClick='playerPlayNewClick("+track.id + ", \'"+track.title + "\')'>" +
          "<img class = 'albumartwork' id='artwork-" + index + "' src=" + track.artwork_url + "></a> ");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...note the double " around track.title also the ' around track.artwork_url.

The double " takes care of any titles with a single ' in them.

```
$("#result_container").append(
        "<div id='result-"+index+"'>"+
          " <a href='#' class='play' id='"+index+
          "' onClick='playerPlayNewClick("+ track.id + ", """ + track.title + """)'>" +
          "<img class = 'albumartwork' id='artwork-" + index + "' src='" + track.artwork_url +    "'></a> ");
```